# How to fetch multiple rows with same id from a table in zend framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Controller

```
 public function detailsAction()
 {  
    $this->getRequest()->isPost();
    $pid = $this->getRequest()->getParam('pid');
    $order =new Application_Model_DbTable_orders;
    $this->view->orders = $order->fetchdetails($pid); 
  }
```

Model

```
public function fetchdetails($pid)
{
    $select =$this->select()
->from('orderdetails') 
->joinInner('products','products.id=orderdetails.productid')
->joinInner('suppliers','products.supplierid=suppliers.supplierid')
->where('pid = ?', $pid) 
->setIntegrityCheck(false);
return $this->fetchAll($select);
}
```

Output

when I'm trying to fetch details of a particular PurchaseID i get the following result

### | PurchaseID | ProductName | Price |Quantity  |

### |    100002346    | product 2        | 17765 |    5  |

### |    100002346    | product 2        | 17765 |    2   |

### |    100002346    | product 2        | 17765 |    2  |

in the above result set all the values except the ones in Quantity field is repeated.
This table is supposed to show 3 different products.

**Here is my php code:**

```
<?php foreach($this->orders as $ord) : ?>
<tr> <td>
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->productname);?>
</td> <td>
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->price);?>
</td> <td>
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->company);?> 
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->url);?>
</td> <td>
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->Quantity);?>
</td> </tr> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

,Please help me out people.

Comment: how do you output fetched rows? show us the code please. what is your `Application_Model_DbTable_orders` model?

Comment: so try to output  `<tr> <td>
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->productid);?>
</td> <td>
  <?php echo $this->escape($ord->productname);?>
</td> <td>`  for now

Comment: still the same result,the value repeats.

Comment: `productid` are the same??? show proof of your raw data source please?

Comment: both productid and productname repeats

Comment: show proofs of table contents. it looks like you have three records with the same product there and there is no programming issue, just wrong expectations

Comment: do you have phpMyAdmin for your database?

Comment: yes I have  phpMyAdmin.

Comment: so go there and run query `SELECT * FROM orderdetails WHERE pid=XXX` where `XXX` is your order id and add result to your question post

Comment: Yes you are right,the issue is not with the code.Its somewhere else.I got the same kind of results there.

Comment: ;-) so good luck with your project.